# How to bypass error "Invalid type "json_array""

Tags: json, symfony, symfony4

I have an entity:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity\Aero;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\Aero\ScheduleRepository")
 */
class Schedule
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="date")
     */
    private $dateOfFlight;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="json")
     */
    private $timeOfFlightAndStations = [];

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getDateOfFlight(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->dateOfFlight;
    }

    public function setDateOfFlight(\DateTimeInterface $dateOfFlight): self
    {
        $this->dateOfFlight = $dateOfFlight;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getTimeOfFlightAndStations(): ?array
    {
        return $this->timeOfFlightAndStations;
    }

    public function setTimeOfFlightAndStations(array $timeOfFlightAndStations): self
    {
        $this->timeOfFlightAndStations = $timeOfFlightAndStations;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

When I try to add field with type json_array via `con make:entity` it shows me error:

```
[ERROR] Invalid type "json_array".
```

My computer says that type "json_array" is invalid, but also says that it is in the list of valid types. How is it possible?

Please, help me, how to deal with this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by adding "json_array" manually instead of "json" in:

```
  /**
   * @ORM\Column(type="json_array")
   */
```